# R: eigen vectors are all null

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, nodes

I am using the R language and following this tutorial over here (for calculating eigen centrality): https://kelseyandersen.github.io/NetworksPlantPathology/Describing_Networks.html

I created a **directed graph**.

For some reason, the following code "runs" (i.e. produces non-null outputs):

```
my_data <- data.frame(
    
    "node_a" = c("Store_A", "Store_A", "Store_A", "Store_B", "Store_B", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_B", "Store_C", "customer_4", "customer_9", "customer_1"),
    "node_b" = c("customer_1", "customer_2", "customer_3", "customer_3", "customer_4", "customer_2", "customer_5", "customer_6", "customer_7", "Store_B", "customer_9","customer_9", "customer_5", "customer_4", "customer_1")
)



 #create directed graph 
graph <- graph.data.frame(my_data, directed=T)
graph <- simplify(graph)

#calculate and plot eigen centrality
 a = eigen_centrality(graph)
eig1 <- eigen_centrality(graph)
V(graph)$size <- (eig1$vector*10)
 plot(graph, edge.arrow.size = .5, vertex.color = "gold")
```

Yet, the following code produces a null vector of eigen values:

```
 #calculate and plot eigen centrality
    a = eigen_centrality(graph, directed = T)
Warning message:
In eigen_centrality(graph, directed = T) :
  At centrality.c:344 :graph is directed and acyclic; eigenvector centralities will be zeros
```

Does anyone know what is the difference between the above two segments of code? I specified that I wanted a directed graph :`graph <- graph.data.frame(my_data, directed = T)`

I thought when calculating the eigen centrality, by specifying : `a  = eigen_centrality(graph, directed = TRUE)` , I was just re-confirming that my graph is directed? Can eigen centrality be calculated on directed graphs? (unlike community detection algorithms like louvain, girvan-newman, fastgreedy which can only be calculated on undirected graphs)

Is this because my graph is "acyclic"?

Thanks

Note: Interestingly enough, the "pagerank" algorithm seems to work:

```
a = page_rank(graph, directed = T)
```

Comment: My understanding is that the eigenvector centrality is not defined for acyclic graphs. If you found an answer why yourself, I'd be interested to read.